# The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code - 1

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
  int r, c, a[100][100], b[100][100], sum[100][100], i, j;
  printf("Enter the number of rows (between 1 and 100): ");
  scanf("%d", &r);
  printf("Enter the number of columns (between 1 and 100): ");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  printf("\nEnter elements of 1st matrix:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
      printf("Enter element a%d%d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
      scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }

  printf("Enter elements of 2nd matrix:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
      printf("Enter element b%d%d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
      scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
    }

  // adding two matrices
  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
      sum[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    }

  // printing the result
  printf("\nSum of two matrices: \n");
  for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
      printf("%d   ", sum[i][j]);
      if (j == c - 1) {
        printf("\n\n");
      }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

**I'm Just A Beginner As I've Just Started Learning Coding And Am Starting With C**
**I've Been Facing This Issue But It Seems That I Just Couldn't Come Up With A Solution**

Comment: Welcome to SO. As a beginner you should first know what you are actually doing. Are you talking about C or C++? Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? These are very different languages and very different tools. Only pick tags that are actually related to your problem.

Comment: The first thing you need to learn is that C and C++ are very different languages. Don't tag both unless you're specifically asking about their differences. (You should also learn how to use capital letters.)

Comment: If building a program fails there must be some error messages printed by the compiler. Please copy complete and exact messages to the question

Comment: Make the large arrays global to avoid the possible stack overflow as @drescherjm suggests (which is quite unlikely, but easy to try), and see if it helps.

Comment: @drescherjm I Didn't Quite Get You What You Are Trying To Explain?

Comment: Local variables are stored on the stack which has limited size. Moving your arrays out of `main`, i.e. making them global variables could solve issues with stack size. But I don't think that is an issue here as they only take ~120kB which should not cause trouble. Also you seem to have a problem with compiling your program, not with running it.

Comment: My initial thought was the arrays were too big for a default 1MB stack but after looking at 100 x 100 x 4 x 3 it you should be fine so I deleted the comment.

Comment: BTW: What toolset have you installed to compile your C code? Visual Studio Code is an editor with some goodies for programming. It does not come with a compiler.

Comment: VSCode documentation recommends that you install msys2 and use that to install mingw and update using msys2 package manager `pacman`: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: @Gerhardh I Have Installed A Compiler And MinGW To Run My Code